# Kafka Streams: How to force quicker updates on stores

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an aggregated store via DSL via windowed aggregation over a stream. 
Then, I get a stream from it via `toStream`, do some small transformation and send to another topic.

In my tests, from the publishing time to the time when the data is in the destination stream, it may well spend 10-20 seconds. Which makes my tests having to wait for it that long.

How can I reduce this waiting time so computations are triggered faster in my tests?

Which settings are involved?

I tried setting `commit.interval.ms` to 100 but it is of no help.

Comment: Reducing the commit interval should actually work... You can also try to disable caching by setting the cache size to zero in the config. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried setting cache to zero. However, I see messages coming as null downstream in the topoogy in stages after the `.toStream()` - where they weren't before. I'll investigate, but any hint on this?

Comment: Not sure exactly what computation you do. But `<key,null>` messages indicate tombstones (ie, delete on the KTable). With caching, those might get deduplicate?